# Microsoft Word to HTML in PHP script

Tags: php, html, ms-word

I want to know the PHP code for Word to HTML conversion. When we retrive the Word document from the database and display in the frontend, the Word document should display as HTML page.

Comment: what are you trying to say. describe properly.

Comment: This question seems to ask/answer the same thing:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253834/convert-doc-to-html-in-php

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: He wants to display a .doc file using PHP.  Plus if you google Word to PHP this stackoverflow questions pop up first in the result. So I think it is relevant. How hever @Todd. Its never good to ask straight up for code.

Answer (score 1):

[wvware](http://wvware.sourceforge.net)

Answer (score 0):

I don't completly understand your request but I think you can try TinyMCE for PHP, it's a Web based Wysiwyg editor, where all you type and format will be saved as HTML code, you can even paste and convert Word documents.

Answer (score -2):

So like symcbean said, the best way to do is wvWare, otherwise,you could hardcode a class yourself, but it will be a difficult path.