# Print word files with PHP

Tags: php

I am using PHP to create a program to accept data from a form and then create 20 different DOC files which can be downloaded on click. I have done all this and if you click the usrl to 20 files, it gives pop up to save this files as word files. Now I am working on printing all these files using one click from the program itself without saving them. This data comes from DB so it is dynamic. Is it possible to print these word files using one click. Also some documents can have multiple copies.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.printer.php

Comment: printer library is a good start, maybe a .doc to .xps convert is another step to look into as well

Comment: You want to print on the server or the client?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your replies. 

@Maerlyn, After filling up the HTML form and submit, the option to print should show up. The printing has to be done on client computer.

Comment: @Chris, I am taking a look at this. I have to enable this on php.ini and try. The problem is that the data is dynamic so I am not sure if it will work as expected.

Comment: @Dave, Looking into this as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can't print Word files directly from browser unless user has a word processor extension for browser like Zotero. An other option is to convert your doc file to PDF, HTML or image format. wvWare is a software you can do this with. see: http://wvware.sourceforge.net/

To create word files with PHPWord. see: http://phpword.codeplex.com/

With this you can save your doc(x) files and add the links to your php page.
Or you can directly download file when opening a PHP page by creating custom headers:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myfile.docx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

// Code that generates DOC

// output the file to the browser
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
?>
```

See forum thread here: https://phpword.codeplex.com/discussions/225901

Comment: OP said they can already do this, They want to be able to print the documents.

Comment: You can print Word files only after downloading. Or you can convert it to HTML and print with browser. See this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772781/microsoft-word-to-html-in-php-script

Comment: Perhaps you should include how to do that in your answer. Do that, and I'll give you a +1!

Comment: Updated my answer. Browsers can print only website contents. Try wvWare to convert.

Comment: Zotero is not a word processor extension for a browsers and will not allow you to print word documents or in any way improve printing of any other sort of document.

Answer (score 0):

One Top of your php or any html code

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-word"); 
header("Expires: 0"); 
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=Report.doc");

?>
```