# to fetch doc file content

Tags: php

```
$myFile = "pdf/document_file.doc";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r');
$theData = file_get_contents($myFile);
fclose($fh);
echo "<pre>";
echo $theData;
echo "</pre>";
```

My above script fetches the data from document file but it display some of binary numbers.

I need to display document file content in to html content

For Example
If my document file is a resume. i need to fetch the content and display document data same as selected file in html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It IS binary data. To view it as HTML you need to convert it first.

[Convert .doc to html in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253834/convert-doc-to-html-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

You're reading binary data. Hence the "numbers". The raw data needs to go through some "filter/render implementation" first.

Plus, when you use `file_get_contents()` there's no need to `fopen()` and `fclose()`.