# Coverting MS Word documents to HTML

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert .doc to html in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253834/convert-doc-to-html-in-php)

I want to know how can I convert word to html so that I can embed it in a web page. I want to use php (I prefer it). How can this be achieved?

Comment: you want to convert to html or pdf ? the content and title are different !

Comment: Sorry my bad i dont know what i was thinking its html

Comment: You know that Word documents can have features (that may or may not be utilised in _your_ documents) which don't translate directly to HTML? Headers and footers is the first that comes to mind, but there are others. If you're just talking about one document then Word can do it for you if you follow these three steps: (1) Click Save As (2) Select html format (3) Stare in horror at all the extra nonsense Word puts in the resulting file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick [google search](https://encrypted.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=de&cp=16&gs_id=2s&xhr=t&q=export%20word%20to%20html&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&site=webhp&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=export%20word%20to%20h&aq=0L&aqi=g-L1g-vL1g-jvL2&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=ff33c7a6380c1b1&biw=1600&bih=785) dug up [this page](http://word2cleanhtml.com/)...

Comment: In the given link you have to manually copy and past the document i want to do it autmatically like from a files path

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/253834/convert-doc-to-html-in-php similar question, further similar questions linked in answers.