# Convert .doc to html in php - Problems invoking Abiword on Windows

Tags: php, html, windows, doc, abiword

I'm trying to get AbiWord program to do the job for me but it seems I'm not calling it properly in php.
I've based it from one of the answers in this question:
[Convert .doc to html in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253834/convert-doc-to-html-in-php)

What I'm trying to do is to execute abiword command using the exec() function in php:

```
<?php
exec('AbiWord --to=html bpls.docx');
?>
```

It doesn't error on me so I do not know what's wrong with this code. I've already added the abi word bin folder(where AbiWord.exe is located) into the environment variables in windows.

Comment: Have you tried to execute `AbiWord --to=html bpls.docx` manually?

Comment: yes but it only works if the doc file is in the same folder as the abiword.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page http://www.abisource.com/wiki/AbiCommand says that AbiCommand at the moment supports only Unix-like systems. So, you need to find what command line options does AbiWord accepts on Windows (they are not the same as on unix-like systems) and use them instead. May be something like `AbiWord -h` or `AbiWord /?` will give you list of options

Comment: well, this is not an answer :( Strange, why it was accepted.