# How to read the ms word file as html in phpge

Tags: php

anybody can help me to solve this problem

I am trying to read the ms word document(doc) as HTML and that should be display in my page as HTML.

or

is there any php library to view the doc file?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to download any special software to do this since MSWord has a built-in 'save as html' feature already. You'll find this in the extention bar when you use 'save as..'.

Then you can use an iframe on your page or something of the like. Is the generated html by MSWord pretty? No, but it works.

Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a post from here that might help you:

[Convert .doc to html in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253834/convert-doc-to-html-in-php)

It looks like there is a few ways to tackle this issue.